# JADE - executing agent with command line arguments

Tags: agents-jade

I download the latest JADE framework 4.3.3. It seems running agent from command line is no longer possible without first running the gui or creating a container:

```
java jade.Boot fred:ParamAgent
```

those command are no longer working. Container must be provided or start a separate jade.Boot -gui on another window, I don't want to do that. So I use this command

```
java jade.Boot -local-port 1099 -host locahost -agents fred:ParamAgent
```

those command is ok, working, the problem is when I want to add arguments to the command line:

```
java jade.Boot -local-port 1099 -host locahost -agents fred:ParamAgent (1 "Hello There")
```

I got an error.

```
WARNING: Error reading initial agents. jade.core.ProfileException: 
Error parsing specifier list (3. - Caused by:  Incorrect specifier 
"(3". Missing final parenthesis
jade.core.ProfileException: Error parsing specifier list 
(3. - Caused by:  Incorrect specifier "(3". Missing final parenthesis
```

It seems jade no longer accepting command line argument and there is no mention of this in the jade primer. I really dun want to use the GUI to initiate my agent every time, coz that is the only way now to add arguments to agent

Comment: arguments should be separated by comma, and I'm pretty sure there should not be any whitespaces.

Comment: @Rémi is correct; the docs show a comma-separated list with no spaces: http://jade.tilab.com/documentation/tutorials-guides/how-to-configure-your-agent/

Answer (score 0):

The argument separator is configurable and therefore can be a space or a comma...
but I'm guessing that you are under UNIX and you should put all the reference of the agent,i mean the specifier(name of the agent,class and the argument list) within simple quotes as below :

> java jade.Boot -local-port 1099 -host locahost -agents 'fred:ParamAgent (1 "Hello There")'